# configure rsync patches in ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, configuration

I am hoping to preserve the created time in my files at migration, and came across the patch files that will do the magic. I configured the paths on my Ubuntu machine. However it doesn’t recognise the -N when I tried `rsync -aN <file> <output path>`. Would be great if anyone points out what’s missing here.

I performed these steps in `/usr/share/`. to install the patches. I already had rsync installed on my ubuntu machine before.

```
sudo curl -O https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/src/rsync-3.1.3.tar.gz
sudo curl -O https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/src/rsync-patches-3.1.3.tar.gz
sudo tar -xvf rsync-3.1.3.tar.gz 
sudo tar -xvf rsync-patches-3.1.3.tar.gz

cd rsync-3.1.3

patch -p1 < patches/fileflags.diff
patch -p1 < patches/crtimes.diff
patch -p1 < patches/hfs-compression.diff

./configure
make
```

It looked like the configuration was successful despite seeing the `rm: conftest.c: resource busy` messages.

```
checking whether -c -o works... rm: conftest.c: Resource busy
rm: conftest.c: Resource busy
yes
checking for stunnel... stunnel
checking for stunnel4... stunnel
checking for _acl... rm: conftest.c: Resource busy
no
checking for __acl... rm: conftest.c: Resource busy
no
checking for _facl... rm: conftest.c: Resource busy
no
checking for __facl... rm: conftest.c: Resource busy
no
checking whether to support ACLs... Using OS X ACLs
checking whether to support extended attributes... Using OS X xattrs
configure.sh: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating lib/dummy
config.status: creating zlib/dummy
config.status: creating popt/dummy
config.status: creating shconfig
config.status: creating config.h

    rsync 3.1.3 configuration successful

    Note that yodl2man was not found, so pre-existing manpage files will be
    used w/o change (if available) -- no .yo file changes will be used.

rm: conftest.c: Resource busy
```

I’ve also tried the following but didn't manage to apply the patch settings.

```
sudo systemctl start rsync
sudo systemctl enable rsync
```

Comment: The `resource busy` is really unusual. Are you building on an NTFS filesystem?

Comment: Where's your `make install`, and to what destination has it installed?

Comment: they are both installed to `/usr/bin/` and the install files are kept in `/usr/bin/share/`. And yes, I'm building on an NTFS filesystem. I've also used exactly the same steps to install patches on my macbook. The installation was fine, I can run the -N command and haven't come across the `resource busy` issue.

Comment: You probably need to run `make install` to install the binaries into `/usr/bin`. Or add the source tree bin to your `$PATH`

Comment: hm I ran `make install` after `make` but it still didn't recognise the `-N`

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is IF your file system stores the created on stamp.

Run this to see if your files even have a birthdate stamp. My Ubuntu 18.04 is not setup with birthdate file stamps. (wrong filesystem format to support born on date)

Run this if you get a date it is doable. If you get a - then there is no born on date and rsync will not transfer it as it is not there.

```
stat -c '%w' fileName.
```

Example

I get no stamp on this machine as noted by the - on last line.

```
$ stat -c '%w' foo/foo1.txt
-
```

Comment: you are right. I don't have birthdate stamps on my machine. How did you get round with this problem on your Ubuntu?

Comment: You don't get around this w/o changing filesystems. 
If your filesystem doesn't support creation Date I don't think there is a work around.

 You could add a new volume and format with a FS that supports the creationDate and copy the files to that volume. Then the creation dates for those files would be the day you copied them over. 
I am pretty sure EXT4 and ZFS support create date. There are others too. 

After the initial copy the new files will have the new creation dates.

Comment: I'm using NTFS and it supports create date too. Though like you said the create date will be the day when I copied the files not the original ones. There may be a way to retrieve the dates...https://askubuntu.com/questions/918300/when-is-birth-date-for-a-file-actually-used